# Loop is running twice while parsing xml in php

Tags: php, xml, dom, foreach, domdocument

I am not very sure why my inner loop data is added to the external loop data-

XML I am parsing -  http://pastebin.com/vGc5NhXr

Code I am using -

```
<?php

$dom = new DomDocument;

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->load('course/Golf/imsmanifest.xml');

// get the resources element
$organization = $dom->getElementsByTagName( "item" );

  echo '<ul>';
  foreach( $organization as $organizationItem )
  {

  $unitTitle = $organizationItem->getElementsByTagName("title");
  $unitName = $unitTitle->item(0)->nodeValue;
  echo '<li>',$unitName,'</li>';
  echo '<ul>';
  $item1 = $organizationItem->getElementsByTagName( "item" );
    foreach( $item1 as $myitem ) {
    $title = $myitem->getElementsByTagName("title");
    $author = $title->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo '<li>',$author,'</li>';
    }
  echo '</ul>';  
  }
  echo '</ul>';
```

Generated output - http://codepad.org/J2vP71rd

Expected Output - http://codepad.org/uzUtehgT

Let me know what I am doing wrong with the for each loop.

Comment: Have not looked into the code, but it seems like only lines with no list below it don't get processed.

Comment: Which browser are you checking?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `item` elements are nested. `$dom->getElementsByTagName( "item" )` gets all the `item` elements, including those lie within another `item`. That's not what you want.

I'd suggest using [XPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) for this kind of job.

Comment: Any reason for the preference for xPath ?

Comment: @swapnesh Because XPath is designed to select nodes from an XML document. It's way more powerful and flexible than DOM methods.